# How to solve $PATH not resolving in VSCode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, visual-studio-code, fedora

After recent upgrade of `Fedora 30 -> Fedora 31` I'm observing that when I launch a terminal from within VSCode for the project that I'm working on, I see this message:

```sh
bash: sed: command not found
~/data/Programming/JS/React vgorcinschi $
```

It is complaining about `sed` because I have a script in `~/.bashrc` that tries to include in `PS1` information about git branches:

```sh
# somewhere in ~/.bashrc
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \u $ "
```

If, within the same terminal, I do `man sed` it will complain in the same manner about `man`. If I open a system terminal and navigate to the same location my path would look like this:

```sh
~ vgorcinschi $ cd ~/data/Programming/JS/React
~/data/Programming/JS/React (ch14) vgorcinschi $ echo $PATH
./node_modules/.bin:/home/vgorcinschi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vgorcinschi/.local/bin:/home/vgorcinschi/bin:/home/vgorcinschi/.local/bin:/home/vgorcinschi/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/snap/bin
```

NB Note how sed works from within the same directory.

Repeating `echo $PATH` from VS Code terminal yields just this: `/home/vgorcinschi/data/Programming/JS/React/node_modules/.bin`

I think this question may come-up so these are the contents of my `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`:

```
{
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "metals.javaHome": "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_231",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/bash",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "terminal.external.linuxExec": "bash"
}
```

The following could also be very important. The directory above is on a partition which is on HDD (`/dev/sdb1`) , my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash-profile` are on a SSD (`/dev/mapper/fedora-home`).

If I open an empty directory with VS Code on the main partition (on SSD) I don't have this issue with the Code's terminal. But I didn't have it on the other partition either before the upgrade - this was just two days ago.

So I am not sure what is the issue really due to, but hopefully someone could help me with it.

**Update [2020.10.30]**
`.node_modules` appear on the path inside VSCode terminal because of these lines in `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ -d "$PWD/node_modules/.bin" ]; then
        PATH="$PWD/node_modules/.bin"
fi
```

VS Code version

```sh
Version: 1.50.1
Commit: d2e414d9e4239a252d1ab117bd7067f125afd80a
Date: 2020-10-13T14:44:48.716Z
Electron: 9.2.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.8.15-101.fc31.x86_64
```

Comment: Is `/home/vgorcinschi/data/Programming/JS/React/node_modules/.bin` in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: Implicitly...I will update the description to show why

Comment: Ow...That's it! I reset the `PATH` in the if. How could it even work before? I will answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's embarrassing. As it becomes obvious from my latest description update I was re-setting the `PATH` once `~/.node_modules` were in a sub-directory. So A solution was to add as a suffix the existing `PATH` in the if block:

```sh
if [ -d "$PWD/node_modules/.bin" ]; then
        PATH="$PWD/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Since I haven't played with `~/.bashrc` in a while, I have no idea how did it use to work before.